# Silverlight Accessing ASPX Static Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have a website that started with ASP.NET and over time has had some Silverlight elements added to it throughout miscellaneous pages. One of these elements needs to change a static object on the ASP.NET Master Page containing it. Is this in any way possible? I had it in my mind that I might be able to create an event in Silverlight and catch it in the ASP.NET code, but I doubt that could work. Any help would be great.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to use a static object in ASP.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally impossible.
Silverlight runs on the client, whereas ASP.Net runs on the server, and never the twain shall meet.

Instead, you can use AJAX (see the `WebClient` class)

Comment: Yep, go from Silverlight control -> Javascript bridge -> AJAX call to server.

Comment: @slugster: You can send HTTP requests directly from Silverlight; you don't need Javascript.